# Single-Page Application with Real URLs

Tags: javascript, url, seo, server, single-page-application

I'm not supporting clients that can't run JavaScript.

I want my URL paths to look like `/settings`, not `/#settings`, i.e., no hash or fragment identifiers.

I understand how to intercept a click event with JavaScript.

But, what should the server do? Should the server just reply to every page, e.g., `/`, `/settings`, `/profile`, etc., with the same exact HTML file?

Then, after the page loads, the JavaScript will decide which parts of the HTML to display based on the location's path?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use pushState. Here's a link to MDN on how to do it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method

Comment: Right, but how should the server handle GET requests to the different URLs?